# Expo task manager does not work in background mode on Android

Tags: android, react-native, mobile, expo

I am trying to find a solution for my standalone app and would appreciate any help. I am try to use the expo task manager with background location. However the code does not get fired in the background mode. However it works on IOS. My code is exactly the same with the expo document: https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/task-manager/

Things I have tried:

- Set up the background location permission for Android. I tested it on physical device and I got a dialog which ask to confirm "always use location". That makes sure I gave permission for app to use background location service.
- When I close the app and go to home page, the location is not saved at all